# BackgroundWroker cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, backgroundworker

I created a backgroundworker to fill a datagirdview. The DatagridView is filled using a list which gets 2000 records from the table. I used background worker to remove the non-responsive UI.

```
private BackgroundWorker worker;
worker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var listAccGroups = vwAccVoucherDetails.ToList(); // vwAccVoucherDetails is the table containing records.
    dgvBalanceSheet.DataSource = listAccGroups;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dgvBalanceSheet' accessed
>   from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

How can I set the datagridView's datasource without getting these kind of errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event of BackgroundWorker:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.Completed += worker_Completed;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = vwAccVoucherDetails.ToList(); // vwAccVoucherDetails is the table containing records.
}

void worker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
  dgvBalanceSheet.DataSource = e.Result;
}
```

Follow the steps in [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for detailed instructions on how to use the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi As many as your machine allows/is configured to allow

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` callbacks on the background worker (similar to the `DoWork` event handling). This will then be done on the UI thread and you won't have the difficulties that show up now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access UIThread from background worker thread, in this case you can fill the grid after backgroundWorker completed, so you can add filling datagrid code into worker_completed method, but in cases you want to update UI when worker in progress, you have to implement InvokerRequired, BeginInvoke Pattern

Comment: So what's the problem with invoke?